# Hash 'value' attribute of a dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, encryption, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down that bounded to the DB. it's "Value" is the primary key 'id' of a table in DB. It's important that users can't see the value of drop-down. One of the ways is using encryption algorithms that it encrypted in server side before bind to the drop-down. When users try to see the value of the drop-down ( e.g. using Inspect Element in browser) they just see the hashed string. As you know, this solution gets much time for encryption.

Is there any faster way to pass this problem?

Here is the example:

none encrypted data:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

sample encrypted data (we want this):

```
<select>
  <option value="HASHDATA-OF-1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="HASHDATA-OF-2">Saab</option>
  <option value="HASHDATA-OF-3">Opel</option>
  <option value="HASHDATA-OF-4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link explain what you want. Check this out:

[ASP.NET Event Validation and “Invalid Callback Or Postback Argument” : Part II](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not help